# What does "order" refer to?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince (2009)*, a flying female holding a weighing scale:

[image]

> FEMALE VOICE: I will have **order**! I really hate children. I will have
> order! I really hate children. I will have **order**!

What does "order" refer to?

Comment: Just to have everything in a right way, "in order".

Comment: Hello D Imam. This seems to be more a question about the basic usage of an English word, rather than Sci-Fi and fantasy. You might check-out our sister-site [ell.se]. This is the sort of thing they do and you may find it useful.

Comment: I have also reluctantly downvoted. These types of questions are not off-topic but they do show a substantial lack of research effort on the part of the person asking the question , as this is simply a question of how to use basic English

Comment: https://youtu.be/H4v7wddN-Wg

Comment: @ARogueAnt. well put, however it's also worth adding that these are still [on-topic](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11627/3804)

Comment: I contradict that this is only a question of language. "order" could also mean the imperative to do something as in "I order you to let me go". Thus a bit of context is necessary to understand it correctly. While from the context of the words only the most probable interpretation would be the one named in above comments, it gets more strengthened by nowing that this "woman" is a parody of Doloris Umbridge, who is known to be a fanatic in "having things where they belong". As this is context given by the HP universe, not the language or sentence, the question is on topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer:
As per above comments "order" could either mean to have everything in the right way or how it should be, but could also mean the imperative form as in "I order you to let me go" or something like a group of people as in "The order of the pheonix", which however makes semantically no sense in this case.

As already from the context given by the whole sentence it seems most likely to mean the former (as it is a common thought in this context that kids usually cause disorder, don't do what they are supposed to and how they are supposed to).

But more important is the in universe context, which is that the character portrayed is a parody of Doloris Umbridge who on one hand seems to hate children and on the other hand seemed to be a fanatic regarding "having things the way they should be" (according to what she thinks is orderly). With this context it seems even more likely to interpret it as "the way things belong".